# Best performing algorithm for unique trip selection using arrays?

Tags: c#, algorithm, function, array-algorithms

If I am given three arrays of equal length. Each array represents the distance to a specific attraction (ie the first array is only theme parks, the second is only museums, the third is only beaches) on a road trip I am taking. I wan't to determine all possible trips stopping at one of each type of attraction on each trip, never driving backwards, and never visiting the same attraction twice.

IE if I have the following three arrays:
[29 50]
[61 37]
[37 70]

The function would return 3 because the possible combinations would be: (29,61,70)(29,37,70)(50,61,70)

What I've got so far:
public int test(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C) {

```
    int firstStop = 0;
    int secondStop = 0;
    int thirdStop = 0;

    List<List<int>> possibleCombinations = new List<List<int>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
    {
        firstStop = A[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < B.Length; j++)
        {
           if(firstStop < B[j])
           {
                secondStop = B[j];   
                for(int k = 0; k < C.Length; k++)
                {
                   if(secondStop < C[k])
                   {
                       thirdStop = C[k];
                       possibleCombinations.Add(new List<int>{firstStop, secondStop, thirdStop});
                   }
                }
           }
        }      
    }
    return possibleCombinations.Count();
}
```

This works for the folowing test cases:

Example test:    ([29, 50], [61, 37], [37, 70]) 
OK   Returns 3

Example test:    ([5], [5], [5]) 
OK   Returns 0

Example test:    ([61, 62], [37, 38], [29, 30])
FAIL Returns 0

What is the  correct algorithm to calculate this correctly?
What is the best performing algorithm?

How can I tell the performance of this algorithm's time complexity (ie is it O(N*log(N))?)

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: The question has been rewritten with new details and still is completely unclear and self-contradictory; attempts to clarify the problem with the original poster have been unsuccessful, and the original poster admits to having started coding before understanding the problem themselves. The solution below is correct for the problem as it was originally stated; what the solution to the real problem looks like, no one can say, because no one can say what the real problem is.  I'll leave this here for historical purposes.

---

Let's re-state the problem:

- We are given three arrays of distances to attractions along a road.
- We wish to enumerate all sequences of possible stops at attractions that do not backtrack. (NOTE: The statement of the problem is to enumerate them; the wrong algorithm given *counts* them. **These are completely different problems**. Counting them can be extremely fast. Enumerating them is extremely slow! If the problem is to count them then **clarify the problem**.)
- No other constraints are given in the problem. (For example, it is not given in the problem that we stop at no more than one beach, or that we must stop at one of every kind, or that we must go to a beach before we go to a museum. If those are constraints then **they must be stated in the problem**)

Suppose there are a total of n attractions. For each attraction either we visit it or we do not. It might seem that there are 2<sup>n</sup> possibilities. However, there's a problem.  Suppose we have two museums, M1 and M2 both 5 km down the road. The possible routes are:

```
(Start, End)  -- visit no attractions on your road trip
(Start, M1, End) 
(Start, M2, End) 
(Start, M1, M2, End) 
(Start, M2, M1, End)
```

There are five non-backtracking possibilities, not four.

The algorithm you want is:

- Partition the attractions by distance, so that all the partitions contain the attractions that are at the same distance.
- For each partition, generate a set of all the possible orderings *of all the subsets* within that partition. Do not forget that "skip all of them" is a possible ordering.
- The combinations you want are the Cartesian product of all the partition ordering sets.

That should give you enough hints to make progress. You have several problems to solve here: partitioning, permuting within a partition, and then taking the cross product of arbitrarily many sets.  **I and many others have written articles on all of these subjects, so do some research if you do not know how to solve these sub-problems yourself**.

As for the asymptotic performance: As noted above, the problem given is to *enumerate the solutions.* The best possible case is, as noted before, 2<sup>n</sup> for cases where there are no attractions at the same distance, so we are at least exponential. If there are collisions then it becomes a product of many factorials; I leave it to you to work it out, but it's big.

Again: if the problem is to work out the *number* of solutions, that's much easier. You don't have to enumerate them to know how many solutions there are!  Just figure out the number of orderings at each partition and then multiply all the counts together.  I leave figuring out the asymptotic performance of partitioning, working out the number of orderings, and multiplying them together as an exercise.

Comment: Please take a look at my comments above and the updates I made to the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution runs in `O(n ^ 3)`. But if you need to generate all possible combinations and the distances are sorted row and column wise i.e

```
[1, 2, 3] 
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

all solutions will degrade to `O(n^3)` as it requires to compute *all* possible subsequences.

If the input has lots of data and the distance between each of them is relatively far then a Sort + binary search + recursive solution might be faster.

```
static List<List<int>> answer = new List<List<int>>();
static void findPaths(List<List<int>> distances, List<int> path, int rowIndex = 0, int previousValue = -1)
{
    if(rowIndex == distances.Count)
    {
        answer.Add(path);
        return;
    }
    previousValue = previousValue == -1 ? distances[0][0] : previousValue;
    int startIndex = distances[rowIndex].BinarySearch(previousValue);
    startIndex = startIndex < 0 ? Math.Abs(startIndex) - 1 : startIndex;
    // No further destination can be added
    if (startIndex == distances[rowIndex].Count)
        return;

    for(int i=startIndex; i < distances[rowIndex].Count; ++i)
    {
        var temp = new List<int>(path);
        int currentValue = distances[rowIndex][i];
        temp.Add(currentValue);
        findPaths(distances, temp, rowIndex + 1, currentValue);
    }
}
```

The majority of savings in this solution comes from the fact that since the data is already sorted we need not look distances in the next destinations with distance less than the previous value we have.

For smaller and more closed distances this might be a overkill with the additional sorting and binary search overhead making it slower than the straightforward brute force approach.

Ultimately i think this comes down to how your data is and you can try out both approaches and try which one is faster for you.

**Note:** This solution does not assume strictly increasing distances i.e) `[29, 37, 37]` is valid here. If you do not want such solution you'll have to change Binary Search to do a upper bound as opposed to lower bound.

Answer (score -2):

Use Dynamic Programming with State. As there are only 3 arrays, so there are only 2*2*2 states.

Combine the arrays and sort it. [29, 37, 37, 50, 61, 70]. And we make an 2d-array: dp[0..6][0..7]. There are 8 states:

- 001 means we have chosen 1st array.
- 010 means we have chosen 2nd array.
- 011 means we have chosen 1st and 2nd array.
- .....
- 111 means we have chosen 1st, 2nd, 3rd array.

The complexity is O(n*8)=O(n)

Comment: This sounds like a great solution for a different problem. As I understood, OP want's to have a list of tuples each with exactly one item from each of the original arrays under the condition that the value of the item of the first array is strictly less than the value of the item of the second array, which in turn must be strictly less than the value of the item from the third array. I don't see, how combining and sorting could guarantee getting exactly one item of each of the arrays. -- Also, it seems like the arrays could have more than two items each and *probably* not all the same length.